# Change of variables missing definition

Tags: calculus

A book says to consider the transformations $x^* = \phi(x,y,y')$ and $y^* = \psi(x,y,y')$ and consider the functions $y(x)$ and $y^*(x^{*})$. I'm confused because I don't have a definition for $y^*(x^{*})$. Is it supposed to be $y^*(x^{*}) = \psi(x^*,y(x^*),y'(x^*)).$ Is this a standard thing?